# Get state value without using useSelector

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Is there any way of getting the state value without using **useSelector** with using it in React Component

```
import { superAdmin, zoneManager } from './navigations'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const access = useSelector(state => state.access)
return access
```

The Error I get is:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component.

Which I get it but is there any other way of getting the store value without the use of **useSelector**

Thank You

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To make the store accessible anywhere (for whatever reason), you first need to export the store from the file where you are making it:

```js
// fileThatMakesStore.js
export const store = configureStore();
```

Then, back in your file, you can simply import the store and getState().

```js
import { store } from 'fileThatMakesStore.js';

const someValue = store.getState().something;
const someValue = store.getState().someReducer.something; // If you have multiple reducers
```

Good to know: The store is just a simple JS object with three functions: `subscribe(), dispatch(), getState()`.

Comment: In my case I am dispatching value with store.dispatch() and getting value with store.getState().reducer I was expecting that i could get updated value without useSelector() but it is not giving updated value without defining useSelector() don't know why can you help please

Comment: @UzefShaikh outside of using useSelector you have to subscribe to state changes, like so: `const unsubscribeFnForLater = store.subscribe(() => { const state = store.getState(); const users = userSelectors.getUsers(state); });`

Comment: can you Plese hook at it I alredy tried to get value like you mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/q/75284557/7017860

Comment: Helo @MichaelJohansen I tried to subscribe to the store and upon the value change of my redux state I am doint the force re-render because it is not auto re-rendering the UI when state of redux changes is it a good way to do that ?

Comment: @UzefShaikh that is correct. Only React components (and stuff like that) will re-render automatically when the state changes. Non-React components that use the subscribe function manually will also have do update their look manually. E.g. if you make a chart component then you have to manually redraw the lines on the chart inside your subscribe function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getState](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate) of store, like this:

```
const access = store.getState().access
```