# React Hook "useSelector" cannot be called at the top level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, redux-toolkit

Hello guys i have mern stack project using redux toolkit and want to access my accessToken from server in client side. I have apiCalls folder inside the folder i have a axios.create and want to access the accessToken after loggedIn and save the token in redux state, but when i trying to call the useSelector to select the accessToken it says error React Hook "useSelector" cannot be called at the top level. Is there another way to access the jwt accessToken ?? im new to this. Thanks

apiCalls :

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000";

const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.accessToken);
const TOKEN = user; 

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL
})

export const userMethod = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: {token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`}
})
```

userRedux :

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'


const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: {
       currentUser: null,
       isFetching: false,
       error: false
    },
    reducers: {
        loginStart: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = true;
        },
        loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.currentUser = action.payload;
        },
        loginFailure: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.error = true;
        },
        logout: (state) => {
            state.currentUser = null
        }
    }
})

export const { loginStart, loginSuccess, loginFailure, logout } = userSlice.actions
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68799543/get-state-value-without-using-useselector

Comment: hooks are valid inside react components. they are hooked into react-lifecycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the store outside a component by importing it and calling the `getState` [method](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate).

Be careful that importing the store often leads to circular dependencies, there is a [redux FAQ page about this](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-can-i-use-the-redux-store-in-non-component-files).

I personally import the store in combination with an axios interceptor to modify the headers before every request (because setting the header in `axios.create` won't work if the token changes). I add my interceptors in index.js and not in the same module where I declared the axios instance just to avoid circular import dependency errors (that will happen as soon as you introduce api calls in redux async thunks etc.)

Answer (score 0):

you can only use hook in react functional component

and useSelector is a hook